# My pointer does not point on the same value when its call in a slot QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, slot

I do a pokemon project with a Qt interface.

I created a class Trainer and Pokemon :

```cpp
    class Pokemon
    {
    protected:
        string itsName;
        double itsHP;
    
    public:
        Pokemon(string name, double hp);
        virtual ~Pokemon();
        virtual void attack(Pokemon * pokemon) = 0;
        ...
    };
```

```cpp
    class Trainer
    {
        string itsName;
        int itsLevel;
    
        vector<Pokemon *> * itsPokemons;
        Pokemon * itsCurrentPokemon;
    
    public:
        Trainer(string name, int level = 0);
        ~Trainer();
        ...
        vector<Pokemon *> * getItsPokemons() const;

    };
```

```cpp
    vector<Pokemon *> *Trainer::getItsPokemons() const
    {
        return itsPokemons;
    }
```

---

There is the definition of my widget :

```cpp
    class mainWidget : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        mainWidget(Trainer * player, Trainer * opponent, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~mainWidget();
    
    
    private slots:
        void onComboBoxChanged(const QString str);
    
    private:
        Ui::Widget *ui;
        Trainer * itsPlayer;
        Trainer * itsOpponent;
    };
```

```cpp
mainWidget::mainWidget(Trainer * player, Trainer * opponent,QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent},
      ui(new Ui::Widget),
      itsPlayer(player),
      itsOpponent(opponent)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->comboBox->addItem("test1");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("test2");

    cout << "Adress : " << itsPlayer->getItsPokemons() << endl;

    cout << "Vector size : " << itsPlayer->getItsPokemons()->size() << endl;

    connect(ui->comboBox,SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(const QString)), this, SLOT(onComboBoxChanged(const QString)));
}
```

```cpp
    mainWidget::~mainWidget()
    {
        delete ui;
    }
```

In my widget, the QComboBox is connected with this method (its a slot):

```cpp
    void mainWidget::onComboBoxChanged(const QString str)
    {
        cout << "Adress : " << itsPlayer->getItsPokemons() << endl;

        cout << "Vector size : " << itsPlayer->getItsPokemons()->size() << endl;    
    }
```

When I execute the code, the `cout` in the constructor print :

```
Vector size : 6 // the normal size of my vector
Adress : 0x2536e30
```

And when I use the QComboBox the cout in the slot print :

```
Adress : 0x2536e30
Vector size : 18446726501852669075
```

It seems that in the method `onComboBoxChanged` the pointer suddenly point on something random.

---

UPDATE : My widget was created as a pointer, but i did not put the key word "explicit" behind the constructor of this one. Its finally work

Comment: Are you sure `itsPlayer`  exists each time you call it? verify if the return value of `getItsPokemons` is not null and de-reference it. Sometime checking a pointers address is usefull, but also check if the pointed memory is valid.

Comment: If you have multiple lines of `cout << itsPlayer->getItsPokemons() << endl;` in the same place, do they have the same value? What's the body of `getItsPokemons`?

Comment: there is my method (itsPokemon is a private attribute of Trainer) :

Comment: ```vector<Pokemon *> *Trainer::getItsPokemons() const { return itsPokemons; }```

Comment: When I use multiple cout, they effectively return the same value. I tried to see what is pointed, when I use the element in my vector, the porgram crash.

Comment: Not enough context, how should we know what have you done if you just show end result and nothing what explains how did you reach it.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].  From what you describe you almost certainly have undefined behaviour due to the use of one or more uninitialized variables (probably pointers).

Comment: And please when you add new information, do it by [edit]ing your question instead adding comments.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I have just modified my post with more information

Comment: Why is `itsPokemons` a pointer? Pointers to `std::vector` are extremely rare.

Comment: thks i'll try with a normal vector

Comment: How is the `itsPlayer` created? I wouldn't be surprised if either that or its pokemon vector has been destroyed after you create the `mainWidget` but before you change the combo box.

Comment: but when I use itsPlayer in the constructor, it works perfectly. Its just in the comboBoxChanged() that I have some problems